# Raspberry pi wireless TOR access point. Open VPN doesn't connect. DNS problem

Tags: dns, vpn, raspbian, tor

I have Raspberry pi (Raspbian) wireless TOR access point connected via ethernet cable to my local router. Everything works fine except one thing. When I want to use VPN, I'm unable to connect to my VPN provider.

I'm using open VPN application on my Windows 8 machine.
It comlains (not each time) that "it's unable to get DNS..." or something like that, but only when connected to Raspberry pi tor AP.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh redir ports 22
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain redir ports 53
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcpflags: FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN redir ports 9040

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I don't think that my firewall is very restrictive, but maybe this VPN config file will help a little:

```
# Notice to Mullvad customers:
# For those of you behind very restrictive firewalls,
# you can use our tunnels on tcp port 443, as well as
# on udp port 53.
clientdev tunproto udp
#proto udp#
proto tcp
remote nl.mullvad.net 1300
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Is there anybody who can help me to sort it out?

Thanks